Movie with medieval obstacle course
This is an old movie (over 15 years likely), with a medieval setting. 
There is a scene with some complex obstacle course. It is medieval style, wooden, large structure, with dangling swords and axes and other dangerous traps. We see a couple of unnamed characters with decent armor (leather or some padded thing, I'm not sure) trying to run across it, but they fail. The main character learns (or remembers) that whoever finishes the course gets to meet the kingdom's princess, so he just goes through it without armor and uses his agility and flexibility to finish the course. He then meets the princess, but I'm not sure what happens next.
What movie is this? It sounds something very RobinHood'esque, but... Any ideas?

I think you're describing a scene from First Knight

Lancelot arrives in Camelot and successfully navigates an obstacle course on the prospect of a kiss from Guinevere Sourse

and here's the scene




I can't believe this movie is 21 years old.
